# Multiple eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am studying Principal Component Analysis (PCA), I have found [this](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf) document, which says at page 10, that:

"*Lastly, all the eigenvectors of a matrix are perpendicular,ie. at right angles to each other, no matter how many dimensions you have*"

If I understand that, then it says, that a matrix can have **multiple eigenvectors***.

*I assume up to *p* if *p* is number of dimensions in original, transformation matrix

So I tried to verify it. Consider matrix {{2,3},{2,1}}. It has eigenvector {{3},{2}} and eigenvalue 4. With help of [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors%20%7B%7B2,3%7D,%7B2,1%7D%7D), I found other eigenvector {{-1},{1}}, with eigenvalue -1.

However if I do the dot product between those two vectors, I will get -1, which means that the vectors are not orthogonal, thus the main condition for eigenvectors failed.

**So the question:**

- Is the statement correct and there are matrices with n eigenvectors?
- If yes, why my example does not work?

Comment: The statement is false in general, you need some condition on the matrix. Probably here the matrix is supposed to be symmetric real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal if the matrix is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix), i.e. $A^*A = A A^*$.($A^T A = A A^T$ in the real case).  This includes real symmetric and orthogonal matrices, and complex Hermitian and unitary matrices.
Eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue need not be orthogonal.  For a normal $n \times n$ matrix there will be a set of $n$ mutually orthogonal eigenvectors, forming an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C^n$ (complex case) or $\mathbb R^n$ (real case).